# Error:Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I programing Windows service in vb.net to export data excel :
Show error in this line code  :

Dim variable As New Excel.Application

Error :
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with  {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from H RESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESS DENIED))

the excel installed on my device is 64 bit

How can I solve it ?
please help me

Comment: Honestly a bit of an educated guess on this.  By default a windows service will run in a some limited user environment, that will in all likelyhood prevent you from running Excel (or perhaps any COM interop).  Can you maybe explain what you're attempting to do and maybe we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: I think it's an Excel permission issue.
Refer to the corresponding blog.
[link](https://jwcooney.com/2012/09/20/configuring-a-web-server-to-allow-excel-file-creation-via-the-interop-excel-namespace/)